# BigCommerce Stencil INIT Errors

Tags: bigcommerce

I am getting this error when trying to do stencil init. 
Potentially unhandled rejection [6] TypeError: Error loading "js/bundle" at file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js
Error evaluating file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js
Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
    at i (file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:1:17836)
    at file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:2:2295
    at file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:2:2989
    at t (file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:1:3612)
    at file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:1:3617
    at file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:3:24280
    at file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:1:3260
    at file:/Users/MyUser/Documents/CentricSites/BigCommerce/Capacity/assets/js/bundle.js:1:3343
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:54:17)
    at doEval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2400:10)
    at __eval (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2317:7)
    at Loader.exec [as __exec] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:339:5)
    at Loader.loader.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:802:14)
    at Loader.loader.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1135:30)
    at Loader.loader.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1234:30)
    at Loader.loader.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1534:30)
    at Loader.loader.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1842:32)
    at Loader.loader.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/systemjs-builder/compilers/amd.js:354:36)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:1545:33
    at tryCatchReject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:1183:30)
    at runContinuation1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:1142:4)
    at Fulfilled.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:930:4)
    at Pending.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:821:13)
    at Scheduler._drain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:97:19)
    at Scheduler.drain (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@bigcommerce/stencil-cli/node_modules/es6-module-loader/dist/es6-module-loader.src.js:62:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)

I am not even sure what I am looking for.

Comment: Any luck? I have the same problem

Comment: Not yet.  I keep hoping that someone from BigCommerce will answer.

Comment: Do you have frontend console errors? Are you using a template? `404 ERROR: http://localhost:3000/stencil/theme/3/js/dependency-bundle.js `

Comment: Omar,  I am unable to even past the init phase to view the them locally.  When I run the init this is when I get the error.

Comment: I should have a solution soon... But try `stencil start` ... It has not stopped me from theme dev until i have time to troubleshoot

Comment: @Omar are y'all both on windows?

Comment: mac / browser: chrome

Comment: I am on Mac as well.  I followed all the instructions from the BigCommerce website.

Comment: @Tigerlady See what worked for me below

Answer (score 0):

I kept running into the same issue. What ended up working for me was downloading a fresh zip file of the theme, running `npm install`, `jspm install`, then deleting the assets/js/bundle.js file before running `stencil init`.

Answer (score 0):

1. take out node_modules and jspm packages then reinstall them in the correct order (from root directory) `rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf assets/jspm_packages/ && npm install && jspm install`
2. Run `stencil init` and finish the wizard with your info... You will still get errors (step 3 will fix it)
3. Now remove bundle.js and then stencil init again `rm assets/js/bundle.js && stencil init`

You should not see any errors this time after finishing the stencil init. Procceed as usual — `stencil start` & see frontend on `http://localhost:3000/`